# Calculating percentages for numeric and categorical variables in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I've got a data table with various numeric and categorical variables for different classes. I need to transform my data in a way that in the end I have a different data frame for each variable, where in the first column there is every value that was recorded for that variable and the other columns show for each of the classes the percentage each of that values has in their respective data set. So each column is for one of the classes and should add up to 100. I prepared examples with the `dput()` function.

**How my data looks like**

```
structure(list(ï..class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), var01 = c(150L, 
70L, 70L, 60L, 220L, 10L, 85L), var02 = c(50L, 30L, 50L, 30L, 
120L, 30L, 35L), var03 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 3L), var04 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), var05 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

*Var01*, *Var02* and *Var03* are numeric and *Var04* and *Var05* categorical in this example.

**How I need it for every variable**

```
structure(list(ï..var01 = c(10L, 60L, 70L, 85L, 150L, 220L), 
A = c(0, 0, 50, 0, 50, 0), B = c(0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0), C = c(0, 
33.34, 0, 33.34, 0, 33.34), D = c(100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I tried with several methods to do it by myself, but given I'm not very good with R I didn't succeed in the slightest.

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: not clear to me. :-(

Comment: @AndreElrico It is to me ;-) (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
library(reshape2)
d2 <- dcast(d, var01 ~ iclass, fun.aggregate = length)
d2[,-1] <- 100 * d2[,-1]/colSums(d2[,-1])[col(d2[,-1])]
```

The result:

```
> d2
  var01  A   B        C   D
1    10  0   0  0.00000 100
2    60  0   0 33.33333   0
3    70 50 100  0.00000   0
4    85  0   0 33.33333   0
5   150 50   0  0.00000   0
6   220  0   0 33.33333   0
```

**Data used**

```
d <- structure(list(iclass = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"),
                    var01 = c(150L, 70L, 70L, 60L, 220L, 10L, 85L), var02 = c(50L, 30L, 50L, 30L, 120L, 30L, 35L),
                    var03 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 3L), var04 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
                    var05 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was going for!

The only issue is that it sometimes tells me 
**Using *another variable* as value column: use value.var to override**
and I don't really know why, but the percentage values appear to be right...

Comment: @Gotemn To get rid of that warning message, you can use `value.var = "var03"` for example. Because you use an aggregate function, it doesn't really matter which you choose (as long as it is not `var01` or `iclass`).

Comment: So I can also just drop the `value.var` argument and ignore the warning?

Comment: @Gotemn yes, you can ignore the warning